# Audience Network not displaying Ads with Admob mediation

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

My Meta Audience Network not displaying Ads with Admob mediation Android, I am only getting requests and no impressions.
Please I need help, I have set up bidding and Admob Facebook mediation SDK

> implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.11.0.1'

'[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ywY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Performance index by Waterfall and Bidding.

If you are not getting bid requests then you need to Implement bidding.
FAN is Currently showing ads with Bidding only.

If you didn't integrated FAN with any Ad Network Mediation, follow instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/bidding-integration) to bid your FAN ads.

For FAN issues, You can check for issues at [Monetization Manager](https://business.facebook.com/pub/issues) to figure out main issues.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as @ZeroZero1 said make sure that you have implemented a bidding setup only. Facebook has already stopped responding to simple waterfall mediation requests.

If Incase, you have already confirmed that you did the bidding setup only and still not getting response from Facebook Audience Network, then you must cross check your integration of Facebook Audience Network.
Take Help of Admob's Mediation Suite (Now known as Ad inspector) to Check if you have integrated all the bidding setup correctly or not.

Here The Mediation Test Suite (Ad Inspector) Reference [Link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migrate-to-ad-inspector)

Use this Ad Inspector to check if you have any errors in your integration. Also, while testing make sure to enable test ads in Facebook Audience Network by adding your device id is FAN Testing Section So that you can see test ads. Refer to this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/testing/platform).